# Real-world dimensions of a 3D object in VisualSFM or MeshLab

Tags: coordinate-system, measurements, photogrammetry, dimensions, meshlab

I have a good-quality, precise 3D scene reconstructed from photographs/video by **VisualSFM.** All camera parameters, including 3D position and lens details, are known.

Now, that the hardest work has been accomplished, I'm sure that obtaining **real-world dimensions** of the model is easy... **only how?**

Nobody on the Internet besides me appears to want to know – no answers to this elementary problem exist on the web.

If VisualSFM lack necessary function, I can use an external tool. Example: **MeshLab.**

If no extant software has necessary function, it shouldn't be too hard to write a C programme or an Excel spreadsheet formula to this end... if someone can tell me all needed formulas.

Answer (score 1):

First part is getting the point cloud on the correct scale, this can be done with GCP that are set to known real-world co-ordinates, or tied to GPS.

Measurement functionality isn't present within VisualSFM, so Meshlab will need to do the job for you.
Once you have imported the PLY file that visualsfm has generated into Meshlab, click edit, Measuring tool.
Click two points and it should tell you the distance.